# What is the difference between if(!variable) and if(variable != nil) iphone

Tags: iphone

What exactly is the difference between

```
if(!variable)
   do something
```

and

```
if(variable != nil)
    do something
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted you have the logic a bit backwards, but outside of that they would work the same.

The main thing to consider is that `( variable != nil )` is a bit more clear as to what you are checking and what type the variable is, since someone may start thinking the variable is a boolean.

Comment: also, it's easy to miss the `!` when you're scanning code, which is why I always use the `(variable != nil)` form; it makes it more obvious what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, you mean to say that they are 'exactly' the same? I also got a contradicting reply to this one below..so really confused now.

Comment: The intent of what you were trying to ask makes them the same (that is if you had put in (variable == nil) instead of !=, which is what I assumed you intended)

Answer (score 1):

They're the exactly the same:

`if ( !var )`
is equivalent to
`if ( var != nil )`

Comment: I think he make the question wrong, what he wants to know is what is difference between doing if(!var) and if(var == nil).

Comment: really?? I have seen in lot of Apple code the statements {if(!variable) [variable release]}  -  in the dealloc method...which means that if the variable is allocated, release it ..It couldnt possibly mean - If variable is nil , release it - right?